# Redistributable Python 2.7 package for bundling?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plugins

Our application embeds a Python interpreter to let users run one-off scripts and extend the application through plugins.

We are embedding Python 2.7 (and not Python 3.x) because our field (visual effects and animation) has not made the transition yet. Python 2.7 is also the version mandated by the [VFX Reference Platform](http://www.vfxplatform.com/).

To make our users' life easier, we would like to bundle a Python 2.7 distribution with our application, at least on Windows.

**We are looking for a redistributable Python 2.7 package** that we could bundle with our application, similar to what exists for Python 3.x.

**Does such a thing exist?**

Comment: How about pyinstaller?

Comment: @xaav I'm not sure it does what I need. We don't want to ship a Python application, we want to ship a C++ application that can load Python plugins and thus requires a Python runtime and standard library.

Comment: That's pyinstaller. Just package a hello word app and you have a Python with the standard library.